# Getting Timestamp error in AWS SDK .net

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to use Amazon's AWS SDK for .NET, S3 storage. I use this code:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKey, AwsSecretAccessKey, new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = ServiceUrl }))
{                
    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = BucketName,
        Key = path,
        ContentBody = contents,
        ContentType = "text/plain"
    };
    client.PutObject(request);                
}
```

I keep getting this error (the value itself corresponds to DateTime.UtcNow.

`Value (Tue, 31 Dec 2013 14:13:04 GMT) for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Must be in ISO8601 format.`

I can't find any place to set a timestamp. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your ServiceURL look like?

Comment: https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com - tried both http and https

Comment: well that's bloody weird, +1 for the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! Wrong ServiceUrl - duh!

Should be https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com instead of https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Amazon could do a better job at displaying this url in their console.